# Eclipse JAXRS POST Request payload not converted into request model object

Tags: java, eclipse, http-post, jax-rs

I have a JSON payload sent as part of POST request body like:

```
{
    "id": "xyz3",
    "model": "Camry",
    "year": 2010
}
```

And I would expect this payload to be converted to the instance of my java class CarRequest defined like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
...

@XmlRootElement(name = "carRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CarRequest {

    private String id;
    private String model;
    private int year;

    public CarRequest() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE);
    }
}
```

However, in my POST endpoint resource method I dont see this happening.  My resource is defined as:

```
@POST
@Path("cars")
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
public Response carsInfos(@Valid CarRequest carRequest) {
    
    System.out.println(carRequest);   //prints { "id": "null", "model": "null", "year": 0 }
    
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Above, the line that prints carRequest prints it like

```
{ "id": "null", "model": "null", "year": 0 }
```

, instead of like

```
{ "id": "xyz3", "model": "Camry", "year": 2010 }
```

Comment: You didn't put anything into your Response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried @Consumes annotation (thanks @David M. Karr) but that did not solve anything.  It turns out that my server was using JavaEE 8 with JAXRS 2.1 features.
After adding features for JavaEE7 and JAXRS 2.0, the request model started getting populated with the values.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever used the Jackson annotations for specifying mappings, but I think the real problem here may be the lack of a "@Consumes" annotation. Because of that, I believe it doesn't know how to parse your request body.